# While loop python : Why it doesnt work that way?

Tags: python, while-loop, reduce

I got a question about the while-loop in python. I don't really understand why sometimes it works and sometimes my loop never ends. Here's two loops i tried to write, for me they are identical, but the first one never end and the second one work as intended ! why?!

I try to understand why it work with `while x >= 10`  and not with `multi` ?

why this don't work ?

```
def f(x):
    multi = x
    i = 0
    while multi >= 10:
        multi = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, [int(v) for v in str(x)], 1)
        i += 1
    return i
```

and this work?

```
def f(x):
    i = 0
    while x >= 10:
        x = reduce(lambda a,b : a*b, [int(v) for v in str(x)], 1)
        i += 1
    return i
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. How are you calling `f`?

Comment: whether or not this ever terminates depends on the input `x`. what is the input you are interested in? what do you want your function do do anyway?

Comment: Also, this is the kind of questions that can easily be self-debugged using a step-by-step debugger. Follow your code and see why the `while` loop never breaks

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the `x` with `multi` in the loop for the first code snippet.

```
def f(x):
multi = x
i = 0
while multi >= 10:
    multi = reduce(lambda a,b: a*b, [int(v) for v in str(multi)], 1)
    i += 1
return i
```

The second snippet works because you are assigning the value of `x` while looping over `x` while in the first snippet, you are assigning `multi` the value of loop of `x` instead of `multi`. That is the only place where both snippets differ.

Comment: It would make your answer better if you explained _why_ OP needs to do this

Comment: Actualy I try to understand why it work with ```x``` and not with ```multi```

Comment: @kjuuria the variable name is not the issue. If instead of `def f(x)` you do `def f(multi)`, it becomes the exact same. Try to only use either `x` or `multi` not both